# $\int^1_0 f (f(x)t) \,\mathrm{d}t =\frac{1}{2}f(x)$ for every $x$

Tags: definite-integrals, functional-equations, integral-equations

$$\int^1_0 f (f(x)t) \,\mathrm{d}t =\frac{1}{2}f(x)$$ for every $x$.

I have to find all linear functions that looks like: $f(x)=Ax+B$

I thought maybe to differentiate it but I get nothing ...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Simply substitute $f( \cdot )$ with $A \cdot +B$. Then integrate. Then you have an equation in $A,B$

Comment: you mean: 
$\int^1_0 f ((Ax+B)t) \,\mathrm{d}t =\frac{1}{2}(Ax+B)$  ?@Crostul

Comment: For every $x$ in which domain?

Comment: @hemi That's right. Now you do a similar thing to $f ((Ax+B)t)$, and then you have something you can integrate.

Comment: what do you mean by similar thing ? @Arthur

Comment: $f((Ax+B)t)=A(Axt+Bt)+B=A^2xt+ABt+B$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let us assume that $f(x) \neq 0$, using the change of variables $u=f(x) t$ you have:
$$\int_0^1 f(f(x)t)dt=\frac{1}{f(x)} \int_0^{f(x)} f(u) du$$
so the equality rewrites as:
$$\int_0^{f(x)} f(u) du=\frac{1}{2} f(x)^2$$
This equality is also true when $f(x)=0$ as it becomes $0=0$.

Differentiating you obtain:

$$f'(x) f(f(x))=f'(x) f(x)$$
so if $f'(x) \neq 0$ you obtain:
$$f(f(x))=f(x)$$

---

So if you search linear function verifying the equality then you have either constants $f(x)=B$ (as $f'(x)=0$) or $f(x)=Ax+b$ with:
$$A(Ax+B)+B=Ax+B$$
so:
$$A^2=A$$
$$AB+B=B$$
i.e, $A=\pm1,B=0$.

Comment: What if $f'(x)=0$?

Comment: As the question seems to be about linear function if there exist $x$ such that $f'(x)=0$ then $f(x)=B$. But in a more general case I don't know what you can say (and this is an interesting question in my opinion :-) ).

Answer (score 0):

Although the answer has already been accepted one case has been neglected. If $f'(x)=0$ then $f=B$ and
$$ \int_0^1 f(tf(x))dt = \int_0^1 B dt =B t |_0^1=B=\frac{B}{2}$$

So the zero function is also a solution

Comment: No, if $f$ is constant and equal to $B$, the integral is also equal to $B$. The only possibility is then $B=0$.

Comment: Well crud you're right. Still gives one more solution editing